# Algorithm to approximate non-linear equation system solution

Tags: algorithm, nonlinear-functions

I'm looking for an algorithm to approximate the solution of the following equation system: [image]

The equations have to be solved on an embedded system, in C++.

Background:

- We measure the 2 variables X_m and Y_m, so they are known
- We want to compute the real values: X_r and Y_r
- X and Y are real numbers
- We measure the functions f_xy and f_yx during calibration. We have maximal 18 points of each function.
- It's possible to store the functions as a look-up table
- I tried to approximate the functions with 2nd order polynomials and compute the solution, but it was not accurate enough, because of the fitting error.

I am looking for an algorithm to approximate the results in an embedded system in C++, but I don't even know what to search for. I found some papers on the theory [link](https://www.lakeheadu.ca/sites/default/files/uploads/77/docs/RemaniFinal.pdf), but I think there must be an easier way to do it in my case.

Also: how can I determine during calibration, whether the functions can be solved with the algorithm?

Comment: When a 2nd order polynomial wasn't accurate enough - why didn't you try higher orders?

Comment: You should tell us more about the shapes/properties of the functions f.

Comment: Depending on what your functions f are like it may be worth tying fixed point iteration, the main advantage of which is its simplicity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's a math problem, not programming.

Answer (score -1):

Fitting a second-order polynomial through `f_xy`? That's generally not viable. The go-to solution would be Runga-Kutta interpolation. You pick two known values left and two to the right of your argument, with weights 1,2,2,1. This gets you an estimate `d(f_xy)/dx` which you can then use for interpolation.